# Stop the page refreshing when the session has not ended ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I wrote code to refresh the page when the page stays idle for 2 min (with stackoverflow help). The code works fine, but my problem is when the user is working on the page the application still refreshes when the session ends. I need help to reset the session in my code to stop the application resetting when the page is not idle.

Web.config

```
<system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="2" /> 
</system.web>
```

_Layout Page

```
<script>
  //session end reset page
  var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1;

  var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;

  setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);

  function SessionEnd() {
    window.location = "/Home/SessionExpired";
  }
</script>
```

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult SessionExpired()
{
    Session["conectionstring"] = null; 
    Session["patientid"] = null;
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try slidingExpression=true in web.config file

```html
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"
    name="loginPage"
    cookieless="UseCookies"
    slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: how can I use your proposition if I am using <authentication mode="Windows" />. and I am using Active Directory to authenticate users Thanks

Comment: Sliding expiration only works with FormsAuthetication as it is related to cookies. After the expiration cookie gets drop.